# How do I install python 3.6 while having python3.8 installed? (MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, kivy

I tried the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import app
```

and it gives me the error 'no package called kivy'. I have installed kivy but its still giving me this error. Somebody said that kivy is not supported by python 3.8 so I decided to download 3.6 from python.org but something is wrong..when I click on the downloaded file, it just takes me to more files with several codes but nothing about installation. I am confused what do I do?

Comment: You should try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: @dantiston I dont have brew and I have issues installing it either

Comment: you don’t _need_ to use homebrew to use pyenv, though that is probably the easiest option. Feel free to ask another question about homebrew if you’re having issues with it.